# zero is greater than or equal to zero evaluates to false

Tags: c, relational-operators

```
i = 0;
if(0 <= i <= 0)
```

this returns false.

I don't understand this at all. [Watch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMVQd.png) I also tried making the statement read `(0 <= i && i <= 0)` when I test them individually `0 <= i` returns false while `i <= 0` returns true.  they both should be true.  I'm not sure if this is a precision thing but I wouldn't think so since I'm hard coding the values in. Please help me understand this fundamental problem.

If it helps I am trying to evaluate if a point is on a line by getting the intersection point and then checking if it's between the x and y start point and end point.  this becomes a problem when I am trying to check when x or y is on its axis then you run into the problem of checking if 0 is between or equal to 0 and 0.  Which it is so it would fall on the line.

Comment: because you have to write `0 <= i && i <=0`. otherwise, it like `(0 <= i) <= 0`, ie, `(0 <= i)` is evaluated first and give true. true is different of zero, so `true <= 0` is false

Comment: Thank's Garf365.  I think that is it.  That was a lot simpler then I had anticipated.  Probably should go to bed now.

Comment: @Garf365 To be exact, relational operators return type `int`, value `0` or `1`. Not `true`.

Comment: @user694733 Thanks for mentioning though, I already pointed the same in my answer.

Comment: @CodyCannell don't forget to accept answer ;)

Comment: Can you try (0<i || 0==i) && (0>i || 0==i) and see if it works ?

Answer (score 8):

Chaining of relational operators is not possible (to produce a *valid* result as per the expectation), you need to write separate instruction to verify each condition.

Due to the [absence of explicit parenthesis and LTR association](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), a statement like

```
  if(0 <= i <= 0)
```

is evaluated as

```
  if( (0 <= i) <= 0)
```

which boils down to

```
  if ( 1 <= 0)
```

which produces a 0, (FALSE).

That said, the claim pertaining to

> *I also tried making the statement read `(0 <= i && i <= 0)` when I test them individually `0 <= i` returns false while `i <= 0` returns true. they both should be true*

is not correct, **they both are true**. [See for yourself](http://ideone.com/0HDiN2)